# How do I print one bit?

Tags: c, printf, bit

Please tell me how do I print a bit, like `printf("%d",bit);`.

Comment: This is a good question that needs rephrasing, but I don't have edit privileges yet....

Answer (score 20):

If bit is just an int that contains the value you want in the least significant bit, then:

```
printf("%d", bit & 0x1);
```

should do it.  The & is doing a binary-AND with a number with only the first significant bit set, so you're removing all the rest of the bits in the integer.

Comment: Keep in mind that extracting one bit from a multi-byte number makes you run into endianess issues.

Comment: @gnud: That only applies when done against memory, using pointers. bit & 0x1 will always work, regardless of the way the value is stored in memory.

Answer (score 10):

If you need to generalize more than Herms, you could do this:

```
#define IsBitSet(val, bit) ((val) & (1 << (bit)))

/* ... your code ... */

printf ("%c", IsBitSet(bit, 0) ? '1' : '0');
```

The printf is equivalent to Herms answer as is.

If you're talking about bitfield in C, you can do this:

```
struct foo { int b:1; } myFoo;

printf("%c", myFoo.b ? '1' : '0');
```

Comment: There is a missing closing parenthesis at the end of the macro definition, no?

Comment: This seems a bit roundabout - why not `((val) >> (bit)) & 0x1` so you can print it as an integer instead of the ternary?

Answer (score 6):

Related question: [[How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c) is an extended discussion of single-bit access in c and c++.

Answer (score 3):

To print the m-th bit (m from 1..16 or 32) of n:

```
void print_bit(n, m)
{
    printf("%d", n & (1 << (m - 1)));
}
```

Remove the `- 1` bit if your bit counter starts at 0.

Comment: That won't quite work.  You're masking the bit you want, but you're leaving that bit in place, so you won't get 1 or 0.  To always get 1 or 0 for that bit you'd need to shift the variable right, not shift the mask left.

Comment: What is bit in your function? And "n" is not used. Did you mean  printf("%d", n & (1 << (m - 1))   ?

Answer (score 1):

The C++ answer is easier than the C89 one, with the native bool type:

```
bool b = true;
std::cout << b;
```

C99 is quite similar:

```
_Bool b = 1;
printf("%d", b);
```

Comment: Bools are generally not one bit in size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "union":

```
union bitshow {
    unsigned bit1:1;
    int i;
};

int main() {
    union bitshow bit;
    cin >> bit.i;
    cout << bit.bit1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would that print the most significant bit, least significant bit, or something else? You can't know, because it isn't portable.