# How to represent a number as a 15 bit wide field?

Tags: c, io, bit-manipulation, field, bit

I want to represent numbers as a 15 bit wide field.
So, for example:

```
Number        15 bit wide filed representation of the number
 0            000000000000000 /*15 bits*/

'a'           000000001100001 /*15 bits*/

'b'           000000001100010 /*15 bits*/

 4            000000000000100 /*15 bits*/
```

If the number can be represented in a smaller amount of bits, 0s will precede it.
I was thinking about bit fields, however when I tried doing this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    typedef struct 
    {
        int a : 15;
    }A;
    A b;
    b.a = 0;
   printf("a is %d \n",a.b); 
   return 0;
}
```

I got this output:

```
0
```

Instead of:

```
000000000000000
```

However, I'm not talking just about printing a number (I'm not interested in %15 or anything similar). I want 0s preceding any number that can be represented in a smaller amount of bits, in any of the operations I do, not just printing.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's kind of unclear. Do you just want to print a 15-bit number in binary format? If so, you'll have to do some string manipulation. There isn't a library utility for what you ask.

Comment: Not clear what your problem is. There are always that many digits stored you specify for a bitfield. For output: how about reading the man-page of the functions you use? The documenation of `printf` is not only available in a secret monastry in the Himalaya at midnight on a certain day once per century.

Comment: @ DeiDei No, as I wrote, I don't want to just print. Thanks.

Comment: @Tree, are you looking for something like `string binary = bitset<15>(num).to_string();`?

Comment: @Tree: You should learn the basics about internal representation of intgers.

Comment: @abhishek_naik: Hardly. That is not C. And the bitrfield serves the same purpose.

Comment: Yeah, @Olaf; just asking the OP if this is *something like* what he wants.

Comment: Maybe you want to use  [bit arrays](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/255/Syllabus/1-C-intro/bit-array.html)?

Comment: I guess, the thing is, I'm not sure whether or not a 0s will precede a number that can be represented in a smaller amount of bits. For example, say I'm doing this:
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
typedef struct
{
    int a :15;
}A;
A b[4]; 
b.a[0] = 0;
return 0;
}
When I'll print the value of b.a[0] for example, will I get 000000000000000?
Thanks!

Comment: I guess I am, not quite sure. Thanks@abhishek_naik

Comment: @Tree If you're not talking about printing, then there are no digits and your question is meaningless. `b.a[0]` is an error because `b` is an array, not a struct.

Comment: Excuse me, but my question is not meaningless.
Anyway, what do you mean by "there are no digits"? @melpomene

Answer (score 0):

You have to go over every bit separately, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define WIDTH 15

// print the m-th bit (m from 1..16 or 32) of n
void print_bit(n, m)
{
    printf("%d", n & (1 << (m - 1)));
}

typedef struct
{
    int a : WIDTH;
} A;

int main()
{
    A b;
    b.a = 0;

    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= WIDTH; ++i)
        print_bit(b.a, i);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c 
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
000000000000000
```

Read more in [How do I print one bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349931/how-do-i-print-one-bit)

Comment: Thank you very much @gsamaras

Comment: @Tree I have upvoted your question, which has 4 close votes, but you didn't accept my answer, let alone upvote it! Why?