# How to print a 5 bit/n bit number in C?

Tags: c, bit

Let's say I have some int x. I only want to print the first 5 bits of x. How can I do this? I've heard that I can do something like

```
printf("%d", x & 0x05);
```

to print the first five bits of x but this just outputs 0 in my function.

Comment: To get the five lowest bits, write `x & ((1 << 5) - 1)`. For the five highest bit, also need to use the right-shift operator (`>>`).

Comment: 0x05 is just the first and third bits. The low 5 are 0x1f.

Comment: The mask `0x05` will only isolate bits `0` and `2`. To isolate bits `0` thru `4` use the mask `0x1F`

Comment: You need 1f if you do the maths

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349931/how-do-i-print-one-bit

Comment: When using this for 32 bits it only outputs 28 bits

Comment: nth bit printf("%u", !!(x & (1 << nbit))); nbits bits from the nbit position printf("%u", ((x & (((1 << nbits) - 1)) << nbit) >> nbit)); nbits <1, > nbit <0,>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are compiling with GCC, Visual Studio 2015 (or later), or Clang, then you can use the `0b` (binary) prefix, so you can see the bitmask that you want, instead of the `0x` (hexadecimal) prefix, which is a little less intuitive.

```
int x = 127;
printf("%d\n", x & 0b11111000); // Prints 120
printf("%d\n", x & 0b00011111); // Prints 31
```

These examples will mask out the 3 least significant bits (1, 2 and 4), or the 3 most significant bits (64, 32 and 16), leaving only the other 5.

If you are compiling with a compiler not listed above, then you can always import the [BOOST_BINARY](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#BOOST_BINARY) macro.

If you want to view the actual bits, then you might want to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280654/c-printing-bits).

Comment: 0b is a non-standard extension supported by recent versions of gcc and clang, but not generally by other compilers

Comment: Huh. Touche @ChrisDodd. I always assumed this was part of the C standard, but you are indeed correct. I'll update to reflect that.